# TestBench fails to open browser

Tags: java, macos, jsp, selenium, vaadin

I'm trying to set up my first very simple UX test using Vaadin TestBench.  To avoid the headache of downloading drivers and setting System.properties or PATH values, I'm also using the [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) library.

To make it a little trickier, our login page is a JSP that we will need to open and authenticate before being able to test the Vaadin application.

Here is the simple test I've been trying:

```
public class LoginIT extends TestBenchTestCase {

private static final String URL="http://localhost:8080/";

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
    setDriver(new ChromeDriver());
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    if (getDriver() != null) {
        getDriver().quit();
    }
}

@Test
public void testLogin_success() {
    getDriver().get(URL);
    Assert.equals(URL, getDriver().getCurrentUrl());
    WebElement usernameField = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
}
}
```

The simple test above will pass on the currentUrl assertion.  However, it fails to find the element. 
[image]

I think I have two issues here.

1. The browser doesn't open/navigate to the URL.  Chrome doesn't open a new tab/page when running the test if Chrome is already open. Alternatively, if I allow it to launch the browser it does so without opening a page (on Mac OSX) so I never can visually confirm it navigates to the URL.

I've tried with Firefox, which apparently has a lot of issues with Selenium, and PhantomJS, which has issues with a missing .lib file in the latest binary.  With the WebDriverManager, I downgraded to PhantomJS 2.0 but it times out waiting for http://localhost:29436/status.

2. If it does "successfully" navigate to the URL, as Chrome says it does, it isn't able to find the element.  This might be due to number 1?

If TestBench isn't able to handle the JSP login, then it will be useless for my application.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  What could I be doing incorrectly that is causing my issues?

Answer (score 1):

Created a simple test example for this issue
https://github.com/rogozinds/testbenchexample

What version of Testbench you are using?
Can you try to run it without using ChromeDriverManager, just download
chromedriver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
and add it to your system PATH.

getDriver().get(URL) - should at least open a new Chrome Window and navigate to URL. But as I understood that's not happening?

P.S I've tried your example with Testbench 5 without ChromeDriverManager and simple index.html file it works.

Comment: Please ask question in comment section.

Comment: I updated to 4.2 and Firefox using geckodriver will open but not navigate to URL.  it once had "data.;" in the address bar, which was strange.  Chrome opened once with the correct Url and loaded the jsp login page.  Haven't been able to reproduce yet.